# Examples of small and middle opensource projects on GTK+

Tags: c++, c, gtk, glade

Can you tell me where i can see a source of examples GTK+ projects (non gtkmm).  It is desirable that be used Glade for design UI. I want to see how to organize program and get experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got plenty of projects in GTK+ in many languages on the [GNOME development servers](http://git.gnome.org/browse/).